# Rasa. Wrong confidence score for non-related messages

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I’m building bot using rasa to response for user’s questions and I have an issue.

Rasa gives me high level of confidence for messages that are completely not related to intent’s examples.

I have medical-related intents but message like “I like coffee” gives me even more confidence than messages related. Also, random chars messages like “laj jfias jjlas fe” also give me high confidence.

Could anyone give me a hint how to fix this? Where can I look for a bug?

This is my config:

```
language: "en"

pipeline:
- name: "nlp_spacy"
- name: "tokenizer_spacy"
- name: "intent_entity_featurizer_regex"
- name: "intent_featurizer_spacy"
- name: "ner_crf"
- name: "ner_synonyms"
- name: "intent_classifier_sklearn"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forced classification into one of your intents, seems to be the issue.
One way to solve it can be like this:

1. Add some examples that are unrelated to your domain & add them under some intent e.g. `your_fallback_intent`
2. Define a story for `your_fallback_intent`

this will make nlu to classify unrelated messages under `your_fallback_intent`

pls add details in comment if you still face the issue.

Comment: Thanks for response. I've done as you said and it works, unrelated intents are cached and it solves one of the problems but another one is that `sklearn` gives me many low-confidence intents.

For `tensorflow` I don't have enaugh examples and probably won't have.

Do you have any idea how to configure/improve `sklearn` to have better confidence scores?

Comment: Glad that it worked.
When number of intents (feature) rises, usually confidence scores become low on some intents. I can suggest few ways of  improving this.
1. Good classification of intents - if training of any two intents match very much then better to train them under single intent and drive the conversation forward by letting user select an option to find right intent (applicable in a chatbot)
2. if 2 intents are almost similar, good idea to increase training sentences for both. For unrelated intents you can keep equal number of training sentences.

Comment: 3. Post processing: You can add a logic in your rasa_core action/consuming app to accept classifications into certain intent only when it is above custom threshold for that intent.

Comment: I think there is no point in adding examples to the fallback intent. is this the only way to resolve these kind or problem?