# Fallback action is not getting triggered

Tags: nlp, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

Rasa is not able to detect garbage phrases ("afdas afadfasdf") and not able to trigger fall_back_action. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

### **training.md**

```
## intent:say_thanks

- Thanks you so much
- helpful it, thanks
- appreciate it, congrats
- appreciate it, helpful
- appreciate it, thanks
- nice, apreciate
- nice, lol
- really, thnx
- thanku
- thank u
- nice, thank you
- nice, thnx
- nice
- Thanks you too !
- Thank you :)

## intent:isnt_happy

- terrible performance
- i am not happy with your performance
- you are so stupid
- you are so bothersome
- you are so silly
- you are so tiresome
- don't test my patience
- dont piss me off
- you are pissing me off
- you are so annoying
- I do not approve of this bot. It's absolutely terrible .
- I am not content about this service of yours
- I am sad
```

### **policies.yml**

policies:

```
 - name: KerasPolicy
   epochs: 1000
   max_history: 3
   batch_size: 10
   validation_split: 0.2

 - name: MemoizationPolicy
   max_history: 3
 - name: FallbackPolicy
   nlu_threshold: 0.4
   core_threshold: 0.3
   fallback_action_name: "utter_fallback_action"
```

### **domain.yml**

```
intents:
 - say_thanks
 - isnt_happy

templates:

  utter_say_thanks:
  - text: "You're welcome :-)"
  - text: "Just doing my job!"
  - text: "Any time :-)"

  utter_isnt_happy:
  - text: "I am sorry :-("
  - text: "Sorry I didn't mean to make you sad"
  - text: "Sorry, i didn't met your expectations. My creators are working hard to improve me."

  utter_fallback_action:
  - text: "I didn't understood that. My creators are working hard to make me better."

actions:
 - utter_say_thanks
 - utter_isnt_happy
 - utter_fallback_action
```

**stories.md**

```
## talk_say_thanks
* say_thanks
    - utter_say_thanks

## talk_isnt_happy
* isnt_happy
    - utter_isnt_happy
```

Comment: I have almost similar structure and it's working for me.

Comment: have you tried with junk phrase, does it detect fallback ? It's always detecting random intents for any text except fallback

Comment: hopefully you can find something helpful in my answer to similar problem 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54591575/8169091 here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have two intents, they will be predicted with higher confidences than if you had more intents. This in general shouldn't be a problem, but you have to keep this in mind when setting the confidence threshold for fallback.

To make it even easier to detect fallback though, especially with little training data and intents, I suggest to add a third intent. For example `out_of_scope` where you add some random things that should not be picked up by any of your other intents:

```
## intent:out_of_scope

- fggsf dnek ofjkfn
- I am hungry
- where are we going
- tell me a joke
- i want to book a restaurant
- jfhr qsaasr fvndveti
```

Now you can add a story to handle this intent with fallback.

```
* out_of_scope
   - utter_fallback_action
```